Python.NET: Passing a callback into a C# function using pythonnet
I am trying to call a function of a C# library from Python using pythonnet.
def cb(node):
    print(node)

code.Syntax.GetDescendants(cb)

However, I am getting
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/app/app.py", line 28, in <module>
    code.Syntax.GetDescendants(cb)
TypeError: No method matches given arguments for SyntaxElement.GetDescendants: (<class 'function'>)

Also tried using Action and Func but results in similar errors
from System import Action

code.Syntax.GetDescendants(Action[object](cb))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/app/app.py", line 28, in <module>
    code.Syntax.GetDescendants(cb)
TypeError: No method matches given arguments for SyntaxElement.GetDescendants: (<class 'function'>)
e3322831a5b6:/app$ python app/app.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/app/app.py", line 28, in <module>
    code.Syntax.GetDescendants(Action[object](cb))
                               ~~~~~~^^^^^^^^
TypeError: type(s) expected

